# Node.js socket.send( ) functions failing to complete before exit

Tags: javascript, node.js, zeromq

In some Node.js scripts that I have written, I notice that even if the last line is a synchronous call, sometimes it doesn't complete before Node.js exits.

I have never seen a `console.log` statement fail to run/complete before exiting, but I have seen some other statements fail to complete before exiting, and I believe they are all synchronous. I could see why the callback of an async function would fail to fire of course in this case.

The code in question is a ZeroMQ `.send()` call like so:

```
   var zmq = require('zmq');
   var pub = zmq.socket('pub');

   pub.bindSync('tcp://127.0.0.1:5555');   

    setInterval(function(){
        pub.send('polyglot');
    },500);
```

The above code works as expected...but if I remove `setInterval()` and just call it like this:

```
   var zmq = require('zmq');
   var pub = zmq.socket('pub');

    pub.bindSync('tcp://127.0.0.1:5555');

    pub.send('polyglot');  //this message does not get delivered before exit
    process.exit(0);
```

...Then the message will not get delivered - the program will apparently exit before the `pub.send()` call completes.

What is the best way to ensure a statement completes before exiting in Node.js ? Shutdown hooks would work here, but I am afraid that would just be masking the problem since you can't put everything that you need to ensure runs in a shutdown hook.

This problem can also be demonstrated this way:

```
 if (typeof messageHandler[nameOfHandlerFunction] == 'function') {
          reply.send('Success');
          messageHandler[nameOfHandlerFunction](null, args);
         } else {
         reply.send('Failure'); //***this call might not complete before the error is thrown below.***
         throw new Error('SmartConnect error: no handler for ZMQ message sent from Redis CSV uploader.');
     }
```

I believe this is a legit/serious problem because a lot of programs just need to publish messages and then die, but how can we effectively ensure all messages get sent (though not necessarily received)?

EDIT:
One (potential) way to fix this is to do:

```
socket.send('xyz');
socket.close(); // supposedly this will block until the above message is sent
process.exit(0);
```

Comment: by design a synchronous script will run to completion unless process.exit() is called, so you're going to have to show some code in this case. Otherwise it'll just be guess work about something that might not even actually be true.

Comment: You cannot guarantee async completion in a shutdown hook.

Comment: could try wrapping it in a setTimeout with 0?

Comment: I added the code in question, please let me know what you think

Comment: Why do you assume a TCP connection is synchronous? From their github documentation it looks very much like this is async.

Comment: I make the assumption that fire and forget should be a sync operation, but I could be wrong

Comment: Why are you calling `process.exit(0)`? A node process will terminate if it is finished (close connections, stop listening, etc.).  Also, pretty much anything that does I/O in node is async.  Not taking a callback doesn't mean it is synchronous - it just means that you can't find out when it's done.

Comment: i called process.exit() here just for clarity's sake not because I do it in my code

Comment: Then what is the actual problem?  Without explicitly killing the process, this problem won't happen.

Comment: Aaron the problem is clearly stated in the OP

Comment: See my edits - instead of a process.exit( ) the same problem may arise if we throw an error. Wrapping it in a setTimeout might work, but for me that's too probabilistic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Diving into [zeromq.node](https://github.com/JustinTulloss/zeromq.node), you can see what `Socket.send` just [pushes your data to `_outgoing`](https://github.com/JustinTulloss/zeromq.node/blob/master/lib/index.js#L492):

```
this._outgoing.push([msg, flags]);
```

... and then [calls `_flush` iff zmq.ZMQ_SNDMORE is unset](https://github.com/JustinTulloss/zeromq.node/blob/master/lib/index.js#L497):

```
this._flush();
```

Looks like [`_flush` is actually doing the socket write](https://github.com/JustinTulloss/zeromq.node/blob/master/lib/index.js#L565). If `_flush()` fails, [it emits an error](https://github.com/JustinTulloss/zeromq.node/blob/master/lib/index.js#L199).

***Edit:***

I'm guessing calling `pub.unbind()` before exiting, will force the `_flush()` to be called:

```
pub.unbind('tcp://127.0.0.1:5555', function(err) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  process.exit(0); // Probably not even needed
});
```

Comment: I don't think a "premature" exit will cause the _flush( ) to fail though. Nothing is failing, it's just that my node.js process doesn't know that it needs to wait til the zmq code completes

Comment: Please see my edits - instead of a process.exit( ) the same problem may arise if we throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simple answer is the the `socket.send()` method is in fact *asynchronous* and that is why we see the behavior I described in the OP.

The question then is - why does `socket.send()` have to be asynchronous - could there not be a blocking/synchronous version that we could use instead for the purpose intended in the OP? Could we please have `socket.sendSync()`?